# Як перекласти з російської "безоговорочно"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

В мережі знайшла кілька варіантів перекладу російського слова "безоговорочно".

БЕЗОГОВОРОЧНЫЙ, не заключающий в себе никаких оговорок, условий, изъятий; безусловный.

Толковый словарь Даля. В.И. Даль. 1863-1866.

Варіанти перекладу - "беззаперечно" та "цілковито".

На сайті https://ru.glosbe.com/
подано такі цитати (чому саме такі - дивно):

1. > Что вы можете почерпнуть из этого рассказа о безоговорочной преданности Богу?
   >   Чого ви можете навчитися з цієї розповіді стосовно цілковитої відданості Богу?
2. > Тем не менее Иегова любит тех, кто безоговорочно принимает его исправление и поклоняется ему в духе и истине.
   >   І все-таки Єгова любить тих, хто беззастережно сприймає його виховні заходи й поклоняється йому в дусі та правді.

Який з варантів них є вірним? Без урахування контексту.

Чи без контексту ніяк?)

Comment: Бачу, що ви стараєтеся робити запитання кращими, але все ж таки: (1) не надано пояснення цього терміну своїми словами українською мовою і (2) не уточнено, чим са́ме не підходять варіанти, які знайдені вами. Ну і до українського *беззаперечно* є ще [багато](http://rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=22&t=1626) часткових синонімів як-то *безперечно*, *беззастережно*, *безумовно*, *категорично*, *повністю* тощо.

Comment: Взагалі слово "безоговорочный" має помітку "книжне", тому скоріш за все ви знайдете мало прикладів сучасної лексики з цим словом. Так що лишаються приклади з церковної лексики, сталі політичні терміни тощо.

Answer (score 5):

[Російсько-український словник військової термінології 1928р. (С. та О. Якубські)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> Безоговорочно — *безпере́чно.*

СУМ-20

> **[БЕЗПЕРЕЧНО](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=3425&page=136)** **1.** Присл. до безпере́чний. [Мартіан:] *Брат Ізоген довів так безперечно потребу жертви, що і сам я мусив схилити
> голову* (Леся Українка); *Зарубинецьку культуру III століття до н. е.
> лінгвісти визнають за безперечно слов'янську* (із журн.); // у знач.
> пред. *Я казав: “Безперечно, людина Є вінець для створіння всього”*
> (В. Самійленко).
>
> **2.** у знач. вставн. сл. Без сумніву, безсумнівно. *Голос, що пролунав у коридорі, належав, безперечно, командирові корабля Журбі*
> (Д. Ткач); *Володіння нормами літературної мови є, безперечно,
> важливим складником загальної культури людини* (із журн.).

Існує багато синонімів до ***"безперечно"*** представлені нище.

[Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE)

> **ЗВИЧА́ЙНО** вставн. сл. (уживається для підтвердження думки), **ПРИРО́ДНО, НАТУРА́ЛЬНО, Я́СНО, ПЕ́ВНО [ПЕ́ВНЕ], ПЕ́ВНА РІЧ, РОЗУМІ́ЄТЬСЯ, БЕЗПЕРЕ́ЧНО** підсил., **БЕЗУМО́ВНО** підсил.,
> **БЕЗСУМНІ́ВНО** підсил., **БЕЗ СУ́МНІВУ** підсил., **ЗВІ́СНО** роз **ТАК** част. (вживається під час відповіді, що підтверджує правильність думки, наявність факту чи явища, виражає згоду на якусь
> дію тощо), **СПРА́ВДІ, ЗВИЧА́ЙНО, БЕЗПЕРЕ́ЧНО, БЕЗУМО́ВНО,
> БЕЗСУМНІ́ВНО, АВЖЕ́Ж** розм., **АТО́Ж** розм., **ОТО́Ж** розм.,
> **АЯ́КЖЕ** розм., **АГА́** розм., **ЕГЕ́** розм., **ЕГЕ́ Ж** розм., **ТО́ЧНО** розм., **ФАКТ** розм., **БІГМА́ [БІГМЕ́]** розм., *РОЗУМІ́ЄТЬСЯ* розм.

Варіантів може бути багато, все залежить від контексту.

Answer (score -1):

Безумовно. Наприклад: "Безумовна капітуляція".

Приклади використання:

- Сторінка Вікіпедії "[Капітуляція](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F)" має посилання на неіснуючу поки статтю "**Безумовна** капітуляція.
- Стаття на сайті Радіо Свобода "[Третя імперія. Спецоперація Путіна](https://www.radiosvoboda.org/a/26848286.html)":

  > Далі має відбутись **безумовна** капітуляція США, окупація усієї Європи, включно з Британськими островами та Гренландією, етнічні чистки та повальна русифікація завойованих народів.
- Сайт [Тульчинської районної ради](http://tulchin-rada.gov.ua/news/aczij-persha/):

  > Таким чином була започаткована європейська традиція вшанування світлої пам’яті всіх загиблих у Другій світовій війні у час, коли набули чинності **безумовна** капітуляція нацистської Німеччини і припинення бойових дій на території Європи (8 травня 1945 року).

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: А, по-моєму, справді хороший варіант. Але наведіть, будь ласка, або цитати з прикладами вживання, або словники, де подано саме таке словосполучення (а не окремі слова).

Comment: Ось, до речі, розподіл частот сусіднього слова в корпусі ГРАК: http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/freqml?q=aword%2C%5Blemma%3D%22безумовний%22%5D&q=e1+&corpname=grac5&attrs=word%2Clemma%2Ctag&ctxattrs=word&structs=doc&refs=%3Ddoc.author%2C%3Ddoc.translator%2C%3Ddoc.title%2C%3Ddoc.date%2C%3Ddoc.original&lemma=безумовний&pagesize=50&gdex_enabled=1&gdexcnt=1&ml=1&flimit=0&freqlevel=1&ml1attr=lemma&ml1ctx=1>0&ml2attr=word&ml2ctx=0~0>0&ml3attr=word&ml3ctx=0~0>0&ml4attr=word&ml4ctx=0~0>0.

Comment: Словників (зараз) не турбую. Я носій мови.

Comment: @Kosarar, а як щодо загальнодоступних цитат?

Comment: Я за свободу. Кожен може набрати у Ґуґлі "безумовна" і подивитися, які підказки йому видадуть. У кожного буде своя видача. У мене чомусь на першому місці "безумовна франшиза" (в вашому словнику таке є?). Такі справи.

Comment: Прочитав ваші коменти і згадався мені вірш Максима Рильського *Мова*

Comment: @Kosarar, «Кожен може набрати у Ґуґлі "безумовна" і подивитися, які підказки йому видадуть. У кожного буде своя видача» — у тому-то й справа, що в кожного своя видача (яка до того ж змінюється з часом), тому це не може бути доказом. Якщо Вам (зараз) видає якісь переконливі цитати, то добре було б навести їх.

Comment: Ви цураєтеся невизначеності видачі, а я її вітаю. Google - це сила.